# storing jpeg image as black background color with square box in production

Tags: java, image-processing, encoding

I am re-sizing jpeg image from URL and store at some directory using JPEGImageEncoder in Java servlet.

Code is working fine in Our Development Solaris server. But it is storing image as black background color with square box.

Please help me for what can be the issue. Thanks in advance.

```
BufferedImage thumbImage = new BufferedImage(thumbWidth, 
          thumbHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
Graphics2D graphics2D = thumbImage.createGraphics();
graphics2D.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION,
          RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
graphics2D.drawImage(image, 0, 0, thumbWidth, thumbHeight, null);

JPEGImageEncoder encoder = JPEGCodec.createJPEGEncoder(out);
JPEGEncodeParam param = encoder.getDefaultJPEGEncodeParam(thumbImage);

int quality = Integer.parseInt(nquality);
quality = Math.max(0, Math.min(quality, 100));
param.setQuality((float)quality / 100.0f, false);
encoder.setJPEGEncodeParam(param);
encoder.encode(thumbImage);
```

-Manoj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution.

Actually source image url was not accessible from Java code. That was the reason I was getting black image. We change the url to accessible and now it works fine.

Thanks.